# Haskell Parsec: primitive for greedy many?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm only just starting to learn the Parsec library, and I was wondering if there is any primitive in the library that can do the following: given a parser `let a = char 'a'`, and a string `aaab`, would return `Right ['a', 'a', 'a']`, with `"b"` remaining, i.e., would parse as much as it can, but no more. I feel this is so necessary that it has to exist in some form or another in the library.

Comment: Did you mean `a = char 'a'`?  If so, isn't this just `many a`?

Comment: Well I feel like a moron :| For some reason I thought that `many` must parse until `eof`. Thanks! (And yes, I did many `let a = char 'a'`.) If you answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `many a`, which will parse as many `a`'s as it can.